# gawk – conditional (that is, depending on regex match) find/replace with some converter function

Tags: regex, search, command-line, replace, awk

My input file is

**input.txt**:

```
News A 1 B 2h 0m 1s C text1
100 A 2 B 120m 1s C text2
Show A 3 B 450s C text3
Tom A 4 B 0:30 C text4
Laura A 5 B 20 C text5
Something A 6 B 1h 100m 70s C text6
50 A 7 B 10s C text7
```

(You see the weird time format at the 6th line, but that was intentional, just for demo, to simplify the logic without additional `0-59` requirement).

I want to apply the following regex to each line:

```
^(.*?)\sA\s(.*?)\sB\s(.*?)\sC\s(.*?)$
```

Note the syntax for `\3`. Valid variants:

- `\d{1,}h \d{1,}m \d{1,}s`
- `\d{1,}m \d{1,}s`
- `\d{1,}s`
- `\d{1,}` is equal to `\d{1,}s`

I need to convert this to seconds, but if this part fails to pass this validation, leave it as is. In any case, let's name the result `$sec`.

I'll need to define the following regex variables:

`$price == '\d{1,} ', $names == 'Bob|Tom|Laura|Sandra', $tags == 'News|Show'` (or `(?:regex)` syntax, I don't know which is better here)

Then, replace the line with the following:

- if `\1 ~ $price`:

  `"ID: \1; time: $sec seconds; description: \1 – buy for $\1!`
- if `\1 ~ $names`:

  `description: \4 from @\1; time: $sec seconds`
- if `\1 ~ $tags`:

  `ID: \2; #\1; time: $sec seconds; description: \4`
- else (if `\1` doesn't match any predefined regex variable, or matches more than one variable):

  `ID: \2; time: $sec seconds; \1; description: \4`

so the output file should be

**output.txt**:

```
ID: 1; #News; time: 7201 seconds; description: text1
ID: 2; time: 7201 seconds; description: text2 – buy for $100!
ID: 3; #Show; time: 450 seconds; description: text3
description: text4 from @Tom; time: 0:30
description: text5 from @Laura; time: 20 seconds
ID: 6; time: 9670 seconds; Something; description: text6
ID: 7; time: 10 seconds; description: text7 – buy for $50!
```

I used this code:

```
gawk -F '\\|' 'function _time(str) {
if (str ~ /([[:digit:]]+)h\s([[:digit:]]+)m\s([[:digit:]]+)s/ ) {
match(str, /([[:digit:]]+)h\s([[:digit:]]+)m\s([[:digit:]]+)s/, arr)
return arr[1]*3600+arr[2]*60+arr[3] }
else if (str ~ /([[:digit:]]+)m\s([[:digit:]]+)s/ ) {
match(str, /([[:digit:]]+)m\s([[:digit:]]+)s/, arr)
return arr[1]*60+arr[2] }
else if (str ~ /([[:digit:]]+)s/ || str ~ /([[:digit:]]+)/) {
match(str, /([[:digit:]]+).*?/, arr)
return arr[1] }
else 
return str } 
match($0, /^(.*?)\sA\s(.*?)\sB\s(.*?)\sC\s(.*?)$/, _f) 
{ if (_f[1] ~ /[[:digit:]]+/) {
printf "ID: %s; time: %s seconds; description: %s – buy for $%s\n", _f[2], _time(_f[3]), _f[4], _f[1] }
else if (_f[1] ~ /Bob|Tom|Laura|Sandra/) {
printf "description: %s from %s; time: %s seconds\n", _f[4], _f[1], _time(_f[3]) }
else if (_f[1] ~ /News|Show/) {
printf "ID: %s; #%s; time: %s seconds; description: %s\n", _f[2], _f[1], _time(_f[3]), _f[4] }
else {
printf "ID: %s; time: %s seconds; %s; description: %s\n", _f[2], _time(_f[3]), _f[1], _f[4] } }' input.txt > output.txt.
```

and got four issues.

1. Why do I see the input lines left before output lines? I want the input lines to be **replaced** with the resulting lines!
2. Why do I see `0 seconds` at the 8th output line? I expected to see `0:30 seconds`. Why does `0:30` match `/([[:digit:]]+)s/ || /([[:digit:]]+)/)`? I expected the `else return str` to be in action here (leaving `0:30` as it is).
3. I use `if (_f[1] ~ /regex/)` syntax, but I don't know how to put `/regex/` into variable. When I put it into variable, it doesn't work.
4. I don't know the internals of how AWK works. Does it test **every** condition? If yes, what should it do when `_f[1]` matches more than one condition (`if (_f[1] ~ /X|A/) { ... } else if (_f[1] ~ /A|B/) { ... }`)? I want to put this case into `else {}`. If no, I'll choose to print the result immediately for the first match just to improve performance.

Additional note: I'm using Cygwin **command line**, without using separate `.awk` files for code.

Comment: which version of gawk ? For the 0:30 it match with your last regex `/([[:digit:]]+)/)` as 0 is a number and you test with 1 or more number. You may have a better result by specifying start and end to the regex like: `/^[[:digit:]]+$/` The parentheses to make a capture group are useless in a comparison. For the rest I'll do test, at first It don't work on my gawk version 3.1.7

Comment: I cannot see the woods for the trees. I guess your main question is how to convert a human-readable timestamp to seconds, do I not?

Comment: Rather than `/regex/`, you can do `match($0, regex)`

Comment: @Jdamian: Actually, no. Absolutely no. Time converter was only a simple example, the main question was how to combine the result of any function with `if/else` logic.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting FS:

```
awk '{print "timestamp:", $3}' FS=' (A|B|C) ' input.txt
```

Comment: I solved all those issues, except one, but I'll ask that as a clear, separate question